# web2py: how to implement multiple filter for grid?

Tags: python, web2py

Can anyone offer suggestions regarding a good way to go about implementing multiple filters for a grid? I'm interested in doing something along the lines of what appears in the following image of Webgrid:

**[Webgrid](http://web2pyslices.com/main/static/share/images/webgrid.jpg)**

Thanks!

Comment: Appears the original image was removed. Here's one way to still access it: [link](http://www.google.com/imgres?q=webgrid+web2py&um=1&hl=en&sa=N&tbo=d&biw=1333&bih=579&tbm=isch&tbnid=iqiMNaQ1quYJTM:&imgrefurl=http://www.web2pyslices.com/slices/take_slice/39&docid=WsCysVCyy0hyiM&imgurl=http://web2pyslices.com/main/static/share/images/webgrid.jpg&w=1009&h=391&ei=jG6mUM-5M8LH0QHFloG4Dw&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=7&sig=114934928724886593256&page=1&tbnh=123&tbnw=316&start=0&ndsp=27&ved=1t:429,r:0,s:0,i:73&tx=150&ty=32)

Comment: Otherwise, just do a google image search for "web2py webgrid", and it will most likely be the first one that comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else interested in doing this, a very [good solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/web2py/filter/web2py/oH7eMYNHt6Y/ocAkNK2h2KoJ) was eventually provided at the web2py google group.

Answer (score 4):

you can set a parameter on some links group to a controller, then on the controller you can process the parameter and in order to this, set a different query to use with it:

```
grid=SQLFORM.grid(query)
```

You can use parameters to put into the query or to use different query types...and send it from the views to the controllers ...

Web2py gives you a wide freedom to get anything...

Comment: Thanks Christian. To supplement your reply, I'm putting a link with some code to a solution below.